# sql importance of diagram relationships and keys

Tags: sql-server

I have searched everywhere and although there is plenty of information I only get more confused each time.

So, with that said, I want to ask you how important are relationships. I'm talking about diagram relationships. I've been told that if the querys are well done it works just fine. So, my question remains... How important is it?

That and, refering to table relationships and their primary/foreign keys, for two tables to be able to have a relationship between a primary and a foreign key does one of them have to have only one key? For instance, I have these two tables, in the image bellow, that I want to make a relationship between id_utilizador from Utilizadores and id_utilizador from Apostas. But I get an error, while trying to make it (also in an image bellow). I you could help undestand why I'd very much appreciate it.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to connect two different things together. A key relationship is based on equal terms. I.e. a `customerID` in the `Customer` table corresponds to a `customerID` in the `order` table. If you remove id_aposta and id_jogo from the PK of the Apostas table, it would work.

Comment: That's a foreign key *constraint* even if people call it a relationship.

Comment: @SchmitzIT, I have them there beacause I need them from other relationsships. So, being that the case, maybe I have to create a relational table, right?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yeah, I didn't know if the terms was correct. It might make my searches easier in the future. Thanks. :)

Comment: @taiko its' not a matter of correctness. In order to constrain one set of values by another, the value types must be the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, of course. Same as in the querys, else it would almost literally blow up in my face. :P

Comment: "How important is it?" is vague and opinion-based.   Would you care to rephrase your question?

Comment: @TabAlleman, well I have a working database (have to make a few changes, but it's working even whithout them) and someone pointed out that I have to have those relationships between the tables. The thing is that right now I don't have any diagram relationships and as I've specified how needs to be specified in the stored procedures (inserts, deletes...) it's working. So, I asked him, my instructor, why do I need those if it's working even without them. I'm not saying he's wrong or that I'm wrong. I just want for someone to help me understand why they're needed...

Comment: They aren't needed, but they might still be important in someone like your instructor's opinion.

Comment: Hm... From what you're telling me I only see one possible explainaition, then, which is to have some kind of visual relationships to help someone else better understand the database, if necessary...

Comment: @SchmitzIT I see now why you refered to that issue. E removed their keys, keeping the rows (id_perfil and id_pais), from the Utilizadores table as I realized its a one to many relationship (one user can only have one profile and one country, in this DB, whereas a country can have many users... the same with the profile). Then I realized that I it were to stay the way it was, I'd have to create a relational table. So, basically, to make a relation between to tables, at least of them can only have one primary key. :)